# Trying to exit using a set in python. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to exit using the words that are in exit, I am trying to do a program were you can input an integer or a string and if num is in exit it will exit the program.

```
loop = True
status = True
exit = set(["exit","leave"])
while loop:
    while status:
        print ("Any of these commands will quit the porgram",exit)
        num = input("Pick a number: ")
    if 1 == 2:
        print ("What the hell, how does 1 = 2")
    elif num in exit:
        loop = False
        status = False
    else:
        continue
```

There it the code at least the section of code that is relevant to this question with a little extra editing. If more information is needed just ask.

Here is the output

```
Any of these commands will quit the porgram {'exit', 'leave'}
Pick a number: exit
Any of these commands will quit the porgram {'exit', 'leave'}
Pick a number: leave
Any of these commands will quit the porgram {'exit', 'leave'}
Pick a number: Exit
Any of these commands will quit the porgram {'exit', 'leave'}
Pick a number:
```

Its just loops around forever

Comment: Your `while status:` loop never exits, because `status` never changes. Did you mean to indent the code following it, to put it in the loop?

Comment: First off thank you for helping and yes that is what i meant to do, i had it working before and i let one of my classmate see the code and i wanted to show him how it runs so one of us must have unintended. Now i try it and it doesn't run the same. Before i was able to use Exit to exit and set has gonna unchanged. Not really important but if i can get an answer on how to to that i would greatly appreciate. By that i mean to not make it case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the program is correct and all you need is proper indentation, so that the conditional clauses are within the "while status" look and can essentially change the value of status to help it exit the loop (actually, I am wondering why you need two loops with one embedded into another).

```
loop = True
status = True
exit = set(["exit","leave"])
while loop:
    while status:
        print ("Any of these commands will quit the program", exit)
        num = input("Pick a number: ")
        if 1 == 2:
            print ("What the hell, how does 1 = 2?")
        elif num in exit:
            loop = False
            status = False
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Sorry i should have removed one of those loops from this example but that second loop was for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong. You are looping and collecting input, but not running your `if` statements. Try this instead:

```
while loop:
    while status:
        print ("Any of these commands will quit the porgram",exit)
        num = input("Pick a number: ")
        # Note extra indents below here
        if 1 == 2:
            print ("What the hell, how does 1 = 2")
        elif num in exit:
            loop = False
            status = False
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put your test within the `while status:` loop.  You just need to indent those lines:

```
loop = True
status = True
exit = set(["exit","leave"])
while loop:
    while status:
        print ("Any of these commands will quit the porgram",exit)
        num = input("Pick a number: ")
        if 1 == 2:
            print ("What the hell, how does 1 = 2")
        elif num in exit:
            loop = False
            status = False
        else:
            continue
```

As it was, your `if` statements weren't being checked because Python was still working on the `while status:` loop.